# Open Command in Terminal Doesn't Open Finder

Tags: terminal, mac, finder

When I run `open .` from the terminal, I get this output:

```
-bash: nautilus: command not found
```

What's going on?

Comment: Are you running Nautilus Linux by chance?

Comment: Remove the alias you have defined for `open`.

Comment: @MarcWilson  that was it. Comes from sharing .bashrc between my linux and mac machines. Much thanks 

Comment: @C.J.Windisch If you are going to share configs between machines, those configs should be enhanced to determine where they are running

Comment: @MarcWilson Yeah I did that after this debacle‍♂️ Lesson learned 